# How to export data from sqlcmd to a cvs format or another?

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv, sqlcmd

I have a query that extract data from a `DBF file` using `MSSQL server 2012`, `OPENROWSET` and a `linked server`. I am doing some tests before extract real data from a server and I want to know how to send that query result into a `cvs format` or another one?

Comment: Why don't you use SSIS?

Comment: i will try. I need to extract data from dbf files every night or synchronize, these files are from a ERP software can i automate on SSIS?

Comment: That's what it was built for. It can read from multiple sources, transform the data and store them to multiple targets, including tables, files, dBase files. You can create an SSIS package very easily from the `Import Data ...` wizard in SSMS. You can select eg a DBF source and CSV target. You can save that package to disk and schedule it for execution with SQL Server Agent

Comment: i am trying to use SSIS on Visual Studio 2017, i am looking for tutorials or guides and can not do it. can you tell me the steps to export the dbf files?

Answer (score 0):

**Export data to CSV format from SQL Server using sqlcmd:**

You can use something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer -d myDB -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3 from SomeTable" 
       -o "MyData.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 700
```

- `-h-1` removes column name headers from the result
- `-s","` sets the column seperator to ,
- `-w 700` sets the row width to 700 chars (this will need to be as wide as the longest row or it will wrap to the next line)